# UITextView not shown on screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview

In my app I habe a view controller that calls several views. All these views are UIViews. That works fine, but not in every case. One of the views that are called has some labels, textfields and two UITextViews. Everything is shown correctly but the UITextViews. The view is called in that way:

```
[[self view] addSubview:tasteView];
//tasteView = [[TasteView alloc] init];
[self setCurrentView:tasteView];
```

I call the init method of the view to display the UITextViews:

EDIT: After a comment of  Phillip Mills this was slightly changed! Init isn't called anymore.

```
- (id)init
{
   if (self)
    {
        [tv1 setNeedsDisplay];
        CGRect frame = tv1.frame;
        frame.size.height += 1;
        tv1.frame = frame;
    }
    return self;
}
```

As I saw that setNeedsDisplay had no effect, I changed the size of the corresponsing frame to force a redraw. Unfortunately that had no effect, too.
Btw, the view is initially loaded in the viewDidLoad of the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setCurrentView:placeholder];
    [self configureView];

    wineryView = [self loadWineryView];
    wineView = [self loadWineView];
    tasteView = [self loadTasteView];
}
```

A method for loading the views looks like this:

```
- (UIView *) loadTasteView
{
    NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TasteView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *tView;
    for (id view in nibViews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[TasteView class]])
        {
            tView = (TasteView*) view;
        }
    }
   return tView;
}
```

I do not know why those UITextViews are not shown. Did I forget something? To show really everything, here are the connections that I made in InterfaceBuilder:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what I did wrong and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the view in code (your first sample), `alloc` and `init` the view **before** trying to add it as a subview.

If you're loading it from another nib (last code section), you still need to add it to the view hierarchy.

Comment: I am loading the view frim a nib usually. Creating the view in code is just a weird "helper" as I wanted to call setNeedsDisplay at some point. I thought I'd add the view to the hierarchy by calling addSubview. Do I have to do that in another way?

Comment: I can't comment on what approach you should use without knowing the app's structure but my first point was that you can't add a subview until it exists, so what you've written adds whatever `tasteView` contains as a subview and **then** creates a new one that doesn't get added.

Comment: You are absolutely right: By calling alloc and init I created a new view that was never added! So I commented it out an added the code rigth after calling the view. Unfortunately without an effect, too. I will edit the above code according to that change!

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial code should be like this :

```
tasteView = [[TasteView alloc] init];
[[self view] addSubview:tasteView];
[self setCurrentView:tasteView];
```

`addSubView` after it is allocated

Hope it helps you